# Possible to create Firebase user with phone credentials without signing in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The user-creation flow between email and phone methods are quite different in Firebase. With email creation, the user must first be created and then signed in. With phone creation, the user must be signed in to create the user. With email, if the user attempts to sign into a non-existent account, the sign in fails. With phone, if the user attempts to sign into a non-existent account, that account is created.

Therefore, for the sake of consistency, is it possible to create a new Firebase User using phone credentials without signing them in with those credentials?

If it isn't possible, regarding phone authentication, if the `verifyPhoneNumber` method successfully returns a `verificationID` to the client, does that effectively "guarantee" that (a) the client received a one-time SMS passcode and (b) that these credentials are "guaranteed" to create a Firebase User if they are used to sign in (assuming a user does not already exist there)?

*And when I say "guarantee" in this context, I mean **despite** random or unexpected errors like network-connection errors or Firebase usage limits.*

Comment: Creating a user in Firebase Authentication also signs them in to Firebase Authentication. There is no way to prevent this. This applies to all providers without distinction.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen except when the user is created in a Cloud Function.

Comment: Sure, but in that case you're not dealing with providers - which is what you seemed to have started from. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [Auth#createUser(withEmail:password:)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#createuserwithemail:password:) it:

> Creates and, on success, **signs in** a user with the given email address and password.

There is no way you can stop that from happening. As also @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, that's available with all other providers.

Please note, that the difference between the [Auth#signIn(withEmail:password:)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#signinwithemail:password:) and [Auth#createUser(withEmail:password:)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#createuserwithemail:password:), is that the latter also creates a user in Firebase Authentication. But both are basically signing the user in.

> Except when the user is created in a Cloud Function.

That's correct but as far as I understand from your question, you're asking about creating a user on the client and not on the server.

Regarding the authentication guarantee, I personally didn't encounter a failure unless, as you said, the limits are hit or there is an unexpected error.

Comment: So, AFAYK, there is no reason why a sign-in/user-creation should fail with phone credentials if `verifyPhoneNumber` successfully returns a verification ID, correct? As an aside, when `verifyPhoneNumber` returns a verification ID, does that ensure that an SMS was sent to the requester?

Comment: If `verifyPhoneNumber` successfully returns a verification ID, then yes. But I'm not aware that it ensures that an SMS was sent to the requester. Most likely it ensures that the SMS will be sent to the requester. If the SMS fails to arrive due to some mobile operator issues, then that's not because of Firebase.

Comment: I'm going to post this as its own question because I think it's important enough. Feel free to chime in!